# Spark-submit looking in wrong directory

Tags: linux, bash, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda

I have just installed Anaconda, Apache spark, Pyspark, Scala on a fresh Linux Mint  install (all latest versions).

To test the install I have tried running `spark-submit` in a terminal but I get the following error:

```
File "/home/jessica/anaconda/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 74, in <module>
    print(_find_spark_home())
  File "/home/jessica/anaconda/bin/find_spark_home.py", line 56, in _find_spark_home
    module_home = os.path.dirname(find_spec("pyspark").origin)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'
/home/jessica/anaconda/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /bin/spark-class: No such file or directory
```

I see that the command is looking in `/bin/` instead of in the (correct) `/usr/local/spark/bin`.

My `$PATH` variable contains the following:
`/usr/local/spark/bin:/home/jessica/anaconda/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin::/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

I also have an env variable called `$SPARK_HOME` that contains `/usr/local/spark/`.

How can I tell my system to look in the right directory instead?

Comment: Do you need the path /home/jessica/anaconda/bin in your $PATH variable?
Have you tried configuring anaconda with spark as per this link? https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-scale/howto/spark-configuration/#scale-spark-config-spark-submit

Comment: I think I need it? the tutorial I used said to use it - and even if I remove it I still have the same error. Also I have set my variable to `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` and `python --version` gives me `Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.` so  I guess it's already configured like it says to in your link?

Comment: @IvanMilasevic the issue isn't exactly where I thought, you can take another look at the question, I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this error I had to manually set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in `/etc/environment`